# How to interpret the following clause with a particular tonality

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, difference

Here is an example sentence from a textbook:

> The man and the woman | dressed in black | then stood up.

The upright slashes denote chuncking the clause into intonation groups for speech. I am wondering whether the participial clause *dressed in black* applies only to *the woman* or both *the man* and *the woman*?

Comment: Do you mean "The man and the woman, dressed in black, then stood up." vs. "The man, and the woman dressed in black, then stood up."?

Comment: @user3169 The pauses are indicated by pipes here. A pause such as that indicated by a comma is expected. I see no pipe between _man_ and _and_.

Comment: @user3169 I mean the first version

Comment: I added the second option since it would match "dressed in black applies only to the woman" that you mentioned, and so you can see the difference.

Comment: So first they dressed in black and then they stood up?  Or were they already dressed in black.

Answer (score 1):

Usually this would be written "the man and the woman, dressed in black, then stood up". The pause in speech, which is written with a comma (or in your case, a bar), means that "the man and the woman" is a group in this context, so **"dressed in black" applies to both**. If there were no pause between "the woman" and "dressed in black", it would refer only to the woman.